# How to add horizontal lines to ggplot2 boxplot?

Tags: r, boxplot, ggplot2

I have a boxplot output in R using ggplot2:

```
p <- ggplot(data, aes(y = age, x = group))
p <- p + geom_boxplot()
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(name= "Group",)
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(name= "Age")
p
```

[image: ggplot2 boxplots]

I need to add horisontal lines like on common boxplot (and to change vertical line style if possible):

```
boxplot(age~group,data=data,names=c('1','2'),ylab="Age", xlab="Group")
```

[image: common boxplots]

**How I could do this using ggplot2?**

Comment: I am also interested in this. The only way I know how to add those "caps" at the ends of the whiskers is to add a "+ geom_errorbar()" but then the line will overlap the boxplot and look quite messy.

Comment: @Casey  Returns error:geom_errorbar requires the following missing aesthetics: ymin, ymax :( Should I add extra data?

Comment: @Yuriy By horizontal line, you mean arrow-like whiskers or add e.g., the mean together with the median inside the box?

Comment: @Yuriy Yes I think you'd have to add the min and max for each group to get errorbar to display correctly. Maybe there's a way to pass the min and max values from the boxplot function to geom_errorbar.

Comment: @Casey Just invert the order of layers and this solution will work as wanted.

Comment: @chl By horizontal line I mean "arrow-like whiskers".

Comment: @Yuriy So, maybe a combination of `geom_crossbar` + `geom_errorbar` + `geom_point` (for outlying values) should do the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found solution myself. Maybe someone could use it:

```
#step 1: preparing data
ageMetaData <- ddply(data,~group,summarise,
            mean=mean(age),
            sd=sd(age),
            min=min(age),
            max=max(age),
            median=median(age),
            Q1=summary(age)['1st Qu.'],
            Q3=summary(age)['3rd Qu.']
            )
#step 2: correction for outliers
out <- data.frame() #initialising storage for outliers
for(group in 1:length((levels(factor(data$group))))){
 bps <- boxplot.stats(data$age[data$group == group],coef=1.5) 
 ageMetaData[ageMetaData$group == group,]$min <- bps$stats[1] #lower wisker
 ageMetaData[ageMetaData$group == group,]$max <- bps$stats[5] #upper wisker
 if(length(bps$out) > 0){ #adding outliers
  for(y in 1:length(bps$out)){
   pt <-data.frame(x=group,y=bps$out[y]) 
            out<-rbind(out,pt) 
        }
    }
}
#step 3: drawing
p <- ggplot(ageMetaData, aes(x = group,y=mean)) 
p <- p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=min,ymax=max),linetype = 1,width = 0.5) #main range
p <- p + geom_crossbar(aes(y=median,ymin=Q1,ymax=Q3),linetype = 1,fill='white') #box
# drawning outliers if any
if(length(out) >0) p <- p + geom_point(data=out,aes(x=x,y=y),shape=4) 
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(name= "Group")
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(name= "Age")
p
```

The quantile data resulution is ugly, but works. Maybe there is another way.
The result looks like this:

[image: ggplot2 boxplot with limit lines]

Also improved boxplot a little:

1. added second smaller dotted errorbar to reflect sd range.
2. added point to reflect mean
3. removed background

maybe this also could be useful to someone:

```
p <- ggplot(ageMetaData, aes(x = group,y=mean)) 
p <- p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=min,ymax=max),linetype = 1,width = 0.5) #main range
p <- p + geom_crossbar(aes(y=median,ymin=Q1,ymax=Q3),linetype = 1,fill='white') #box
p <- p + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd,ymax=mean+sd),linetype = 3,width = 0.25) #sd range
p <- p + geom_point() # mean
# drawning outliers if any
if(length(out) >0) p <- p + geom_point(data=out,aes(x=x,y=y),shape=4) 
p <- p + scale_x_discrete(name= "Group")
p <- p + scale_y_continuous(name= "Age")
p + opts(panel.background = theme_rect(fill = "white",colour = NA))
```

The result is:

[image: advanced boxplot with ggplot2]

and the same data with smaller range (boxplot `coef = 0.5`)

[image: boxplot with outliers]

Comment: Looks nice. How about outliers?! Your whiskers show the min/max, but in case there're some outliers they should show Q1/Q3 ± 1.5 x IQR, instead (at least, for a Tukey bxp). You can get outlying values (according to *this* definition) by using `boxplot.stats` (see the vector named `out`), as well as the five numbers btw, and add them with a `geom_point`. Otherwise, +1.

Comment: @chl Thank you for noting! Added outliers and correction of interval. Code maybe is not so beautiful, but works well.

Comment: (+1) I didn't manage to do better myself (i.e., alternating plotting layers -- not very pretty, but works the way we want)

Answer (score 4):

There is a simpler solution using `stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar')`

I provide an example:

```
bp <- ggplot(iris, aes(factor(Species), Sepal.Width, fill = Species))
bp + geom_boxplot() + stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar')
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that it looks better if stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') on the first line as it hides the vertical line.

```
    bp <- ggplot(iris, aes(factor(Species), Sepal.Width, fill = Species))+     stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar')
    bp + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure why this is here rather than SO